# Change the width of the "Language Indicator" in the taskbar

Tags: windows, fonts, taskbar, language-bar

After applying new theme on Windows 10, the font of the taskbar became bigger, so the word ENG was cropped on both sides how shown in image:
[Cropped Input Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUESh.png)

How can I increase the width of the Input Indicator? Or, as alternative, reduce font size in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to decrease font in the Language Indicator. I did the following steps:
Control Panel → Language → Advanced settings → check box "use the desktop language bar when it's available" → Options. 
In the Language Bar tab select "Floating on Desktop". 
After that I moved the Language Bar to the bottom of the screen in right corner and slided it to the left – it has docked itself in the taskbar. Finally, I clicked Options (downhead arrow or right click) and unchecked "Help Button" and "Additional icons in taskbar". This is what I've got:

[Intended Language Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13BBj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- Right-Click on your desktop and select Display Settings
- Then go to Advanced Display Settings > Advanced sizing of text and other items
- On the section 'Change only the text size' try changing the size of the items listed in there and see if it helps.

Also are you using another software to change the theme? That doesn't looks like a standard Windows 10 taskbar, if you are using another software to change the theme or the taskbar, you will probably find an option to change the text sizes in that software's settings.

Comment: The theme I'm using is a standard windows .msstyle theme [link](https://skinpacks.com/download/windows-7/fire-skin-pack)

I've tried to change the size in the Advanced Display Settings, but all remains intact. It seems the only way to change the font of the taskbar is to edit .msstyle file itself.